# SQLAlchemy + MySQL Large Table Performance Advice

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

So I started capturing data from a Crypto Currency market using their Push update service. The Push udpates result in an average of approximately 60k updates per hour. I have about 3 weeks worth of data resulting a table with over 32 million rows at over 4 GB. Even simple queries of this table take just under 15 seconds to return. (Ubuntu desktop 16.04 running on an 8 core AMD with 16 GB RAM.)

Example Slow Query (takes between 12 and 15 seconds):

```
SELECT MAX(Update_Time) FROM `push_updates`
```

I imagine there are several ways of improving performance but I'm thinking the easiest is to break up the large table into smaller ones. Each update comes as a dict with several keys. I figure the 2 easiest options are:

1) I could create a table per key but this would require replicating 2 pieces of data for each row in each of several tables (or at least a primary key linked to these 2 piece of data).
2) I could keep the updates table as is but break it up by day. This would result in a table with approximately 1.5 million rows. (If this is still slow I could break it into 12 or 6 hour chunks instead.)

While I am open to other suggestions, my preference at this point is for option #2 - break up the table by day. The primary issue this raises for me is that I have built my code using the SQLAlchemy ORM and declarative_base. Now I need to find some way of dynamically creating a class for the new tables being created daily.

Here's the Push_Update table definition:

```
class Push_Updates(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'push_updates'
    __table_args__ = { 'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB' }

    ID = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    Update_Time = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,6'), nullable=False, unique=False)
    Mrkt_ID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('markets.ID'))
    Market = relationship(Markets)
    Last = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,9'), nullable = False)
    Quote_Volume = Column(NUMERIC(precision='26,9'), nullable = False)
    Base_Volume = Column(NUMERIC(precision='26,9'), nullable = False)
    Percent_Change = Column(NUMERIC(precision='12,9'), nullable = False)
    High_24 = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,9'), nullable = False)
    Highest_Bid = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,9'), nullable = False)
    Low_24 = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,9'), nullable = False)
    Lowest_Ask = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,9'), nullable = False)
    is_Frozen = Column(Boolean, nullable = True)
```

At first I considered that I was overthinking this and it was simply a matter of instantiating the Push_Update class and changing the `__tablename__` attribute. But then creating the table was quite as simple as I'd hoped. I haven't figured out how to create the table, let alone create a dynamic class based on Push_Update for loading up the DB and retrieving data based on a time range.

Is this outside the use-case for SQLAlchemy and I need to go back to raw SQL?

Comment: do you have an index on the `Update_Time` column?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Originally Update_Time was set to be Unique but that didn't work as I had some updates that included more than 1 market at the same time. So I needed to remove the Unique trait. This whole DB was built via these declarative_base object and when I build them by hand I index most fields. Is there a way to tell declarative_base to index the field? (I looked, briefly, and didn't find anything. Anyways that 15 second query just completed in 0.0001 seconds so that fixed things nicely - for now. Long term I'm going to be adding a lot of data and likely still need a solution.

Comment: Try this: `Update_Time = Column(NUMERIC(precision='16,6'), nullable=False, index=True)` or in MySQL: `alter table push_updates add index ix_update_time (Update_Time)`